# Association Analysis using Tweets/twittR package

Tags: r, twitter

I'm new to R and was wondering if is possible using R,
to get a list of users who tweet using the word cats for example and then 
go through their timeline and see did they tweet using the word dogs for example.

I have managed using the twitteR package to get a list of user names and their tweets and put them into a dataframe. I just don't know how to go about doing the rest or if it is even possible.

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hello John! Welcome to Stack Overflow. I believe that this question is completely in good faith, unfortunately it's a little bit broad. Generally good questions on stack overflow show some code and people can then figure out what's wrong with the code. Please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and try writing some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

John I am not sure if I understand correctly what you are trying to achieve. But I am assuming that the dataframe also contains a time stamp of the tweet. If that is the case, then you can group by the user and arrange in ascending order as per the timestamp. Thereafter you could use `grepl()` for 'dogs' or any other word you are searching for.